# How do you set the width of tabs in a TabbedPage in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm using a TabbedPage type in my Xamarin app. I've got the icons and content working perfectly.

The Problem: I can't see to find any way to setting the width of a tab. I want it to be such that the tab widths stretch to match the screen on which they are being rendered

I've tried using a TabbedPageRenderer for Android but none of the properties on their seem to be non-zero so I cannot perform the calculation manually

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:IGNORETHIS="clr-namespace:IGNORETHIS;assembly=IGNORETHIS"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            x:Class="IGNORETHIS" <!-- INTENTIONAL -->
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom">

    <!-- Account Page -->
    <ContentPage Title="Account"
                 Icon="AccountTabIcon.png">
        <StackLayout>
           <!-- Blabla some stuff -->
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>

    <!-- Settings Page -->
    <ContentPage Title="Settings" 
                 Icon="SettingsTabIcon.png"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

What I would like is a set of tabs that take up the entire width of the screen. This should be default behavior!

Comment: Have you tried setting HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"

Comment: but on what element would I set the HorizontalOptions property? It isn't available on the TabbedPage or the ContentPage. That seems to be a property of individual elements like Labels and Buttons

Comment: maybe you could use custom renderer to achieve it

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT That's what I'm doing but it doesn't seem to do the job as mentioned in the description